# What is the prefered encoding to store resource text files that need to be translated?

Tags: character-encoding

And why?

what character encoding trouble have you had and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translation implies that you wish to add resource text files in other languages, which means you will wish to use some form of unicode. Using windows you might decide upon UTF16, although UTF8 is also very common.

Answer (score 4):

UTF-8 should be the best choice. Will work with all languages and very well supported among the applications.